# Unable To Launch Android SDK with Eclipse On Ubuntu 11.1

Tags: android, eclipse

I am new to using the eclipse IDE but I installed eclipse and the android SDK and wrote a simple hello world program a few weeks ago. So I know that it was working fine.

I have since updated to Ubuntu 11.1 from the previous version on my desktop.

Now when I open eclipse and the hello world android folder and try to compile it doesn't run.

I know that I have to launch the emulator but I don't know how, I have tried by navigating the sdk folder in the /opt/android-sdk-linux_x86/tools and also can't seem to find any references to running the emulator from within eclipse itself.

I know that I am probably missing something straightforward but please help

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you give us specific errors from the console in eclipse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

launch the emulator from platform-tools directory.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have any emulators defined? Perhaps they were deleted/lost in the upgrade.  Check out `Window > Android SDK and AVD Manager`.